# RShiny - How to remove R previous sessions and histories on run time?

Tags: r, session, shiny-server, shiny

How can I remove R previous sessions and histories on run time?

We installed the R Shiny Server in our own server, and our app keeps reading the **data** from the history, or session, or cache so we get errors or the plot is not rendered at all whenever we update our files - `ui.R, server.R and global.R`.

I have this line before other lines in `global.R`,

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
```

But it still does not work.

The app works fine in my localhost though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `touch` the `ui.r` and `server.r` file that your application will reaload automatically or reload it using:
`reload shiny-server` in command line

Comment: what do you mean by `touch`?